# Problema al dockerizar api spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

si alguien me puede dar una mano con este error.
tengo una api rest spring boot que genera reportes en PDF con jasper Report. el problema es que al dockerizarla me sale el siguiente error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [reportPDF1.jasper] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/informes-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/reportPDF1.jasper

### Código fuente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que la ayuda sea mas efectiva, te recomiendo que cambies esas imagenes por codigo en texto con el formato adecuado. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema es que estás incluyendo en Docker unicamente los binarios de la compilación de tu programa (el JAR ó WAR) por ello cuando tu programa busca en el classpath algo relacionado con tu reporte no lo encuentra y lanza una excepción. Retomando la respuesta en comentarios de **eventHandler**, deberías en lugar de proporcionar capturas, proporcionar el formato del código y en capturas puedes indicar la estructura de tu proyecto o alguna otra cosa que sirva para dar un poco más de contexto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

he tenido errores similares y fue que los recursos llamados con classpath funcionara bien es su local ya que este tiene acceso total. Pero supongo que al momento de dockerizar la aplicación debe estar pasando de alguna manera ya sea con un COPY o ADD al contenedor para su posterior despliegue, con un capa en Dockerfile:

```
RUN java -java aplicacion.jar
```

Elimine es línea del Dockerfile para poder agregar los siguiente.

Tendría que agregar una capa extra donde se descomprime el archivo jar:

```
RUN jar -xf aplicacion.jar
```

Este comando generar carpeta genéricas que son: org y BOOT-INF (en esta carpeta estan los recursos y la aplicación ya tendría que tener acceso a los recursos). Pero ahora bien se tiene otro problema de como se indica a spring que los recursos están esa carpeta, y es muy fácil ya que spring cuenta con una clase laucher genérica que puede levantar la aplicación, con la siguiente capa:

```
CMD ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Referencia: [Desempaquetado-del-JAR-ejecutable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.efficient)